# Want to know what a specific MATLAB syntax means

Tags: matlab

I wanted to know what exactly `DX ( (j+1): (j+FM(i)) )` in the following means :

```
FM = [3,4,5]
CM = [0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0]


j = 0;
for i = 1:length(FM)
    DX ( (j+1): (j+FM(i)) )  =  ( CM(i+1) - CM (i) )/ FM (i);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down.

In general, `X(A:B)` means we are referring to the `A`th through `B`th elements of `X`.  So if `A=1` and `B=2`, `X(A:B)` is referring to the 1st and 2nd elements of X.

In the example you've provided, we have:

`DX((j+1):(j+FM(i)))`, which means the code is referencing `DX` from the `(j+i)`th element through the `(j+FM(i))`th element.  From the code, `j=0`, and `i` is being used to iterate over the length of `FM`.

Putting it all together, in the first pass of the loop, the code is referencing `DX(1:3)`, in the second pass it is referencing `DX(1:4)`, and in the third and final pass it is referencing `DX(1:5)`.

Now, in the code you posted that reference is being used to make an assignment to the variable `DX` at the indices mentioned above.  Specifically, at each pass through the loop it is attempting to assign `(CM(i+1) - CM(i))/ FM (i)` to the indexed portion of `DX`.

Because of the way the code is written, the first two loops may assign values to `DX(1:3)` and `DX(1:4)`, but the final iteration appears to overate all these values by writing to `DX(1:5)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of indexing a matrix.  When you see something like `matrix(expr1 : expr2)` it is indexing a range of the matrix starting at whatever `expr1` evaluates to and ending at whatever `expr2` evaluates to.  For example `DX(1:5)` would give me the first 5 elements of a matrix (MATLAB uses 1-based indexing).  I'm not sure I understand the point of using `j` as it never changes within the loop body and is always 0, but this is going to do give you elements 1 through 3 in the first iteration of the loop (FM(i) with i = 1 gives you back 3), elements 1 through 4 in the second iteration (FM(i) with i = 2 gives you back 4), and elements 1 through 5 in the last iteration (FM(i) with i = 3 gives you back 5).

Answer (score 1):

`DX ( (j+1): (j+FM(i)) )` is a vector, that starts with the `j+1`th element of `DX`, and includes all the elements up to `j+FM(i)`.

If `DX=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]`, `j=4`, `FM=[3 7 5 9]` and `i=2`, then `DX ( (j+1): (j+FM(i)) )=DX(5:11)` which is the 5th to 11th elements of `DX`, which is `[4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`.